# Porque quem pergunta não elege a melhor resposta?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Percebi que muitas pessoas fazem perguntas e aparentemente esquecem que as fizeram.

A pergunta é interessante, muitos se dedicam a responder com precisão, porém o autor da pergunta nunca elege a melhor resposta.

Por que isso acontece?

Comment: Votando para migrar está pergunta para o [meta]. Lá é o lugar adequado para se discutir o site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pode ser por costume da pessoa sempre pesquisar respostas na internet, copiar/colar a solução e fechar o link. Muitos não tem o costume de participar de comunidades, então não sabem a importância que tem o feedback de uma resposta. Ou simplesmente por falta de educação que é algo que vemos bastante acontecer na vida online e offline.

Comment: Para mim era por falta de informação, desconhecer o formato do site, justamente por isso havia postado a pergunta na comunidade principal, não era para gerar um debate, apenas para informar os desavisados.

Comment: Quando alguém te da um "bom dia!" você não responde? Quando você está perdido e pede informações a um estranho na rua, você não agradece depois? Para mim isso é relacionado a educação da pessoa.

Comment: Acho que um pouco de falta de educação, um pouco falta de informação. Não é todo mundo que "sabe que tem que dar bom dia", mas também deveria ir atrás para entender o que o bom dia significa dentro daquela cultura. Mais ou menos isso.

Answer (score 12):

Quem escolhe a melhor resposta não é obrigatóriamente quem pergunta.

A comunidade vota a melhor resposta, quem pergunta deve aceitar a resposta que melhor resolve o seu problema/pergunta. Nem sempre estes dois casos são coincidêntes.

Comment: Eu não posso editar a sua resposta, mas deveria ser "deve aceitar a resposta que melhor...", não?
Fora isso, ele está falando justamente das respostas não serem aceitas, mesmo com tanto esforço.

Comment: @felipe.avelar, certíssimo, obrigado

Comment: Existe inclusive uma medalha para quem tem uma resposta com pontuação maior do que a aceita por quem fez a pergunta.

Answer (score 5):

As vezes as respostas podem ser boas mas não resolvem a questão do usuário que fez a pergunta.